# Is there a standard approach for dealing with unordered arrays (sets) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, set

I have a table that contains pairs of words in two separate columns.  The order of the words is often important, but there are times when I simply want to aggregate based on the two words, regardless of order.  Is there a simple way to treat two rows with the same words but with different orders (one row the opposite of the other) as the same "set"?  In other words, treat:

```
apple orange
orange apple
```

as:

```
(apple,orange)
(apple,orange)
```

Comment: Are your words actually stored in arrays? The question seems to imply they are stored as separate columns, but the title talks about arrays

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no built-in way at this time.

### As arrays

If you consistently normalize them on save you can treat arrays as sets, by always storing them sorted and de-duplicated. It'd be great if PostgreSQL had a built-in C function to do this, but it doesn't. I took a look at writing one but the C array API is *horrible*, so even though I've written a bunch of extensions I just backed carefully away from this one.

If you don't mind moderately icky performance you can do it in SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_uniq_sort(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT f ORDER BY f) FROM unnest($1) f;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

then wrap all saves in calls to `array_uniq_sort` or enforce it with a trigger. You can then just compare your arrays for equality. You could avoid the `array_uniq_sort` calls for data from the app if you instead just did the sort/unique on the app side instead.

If you do this *please* store your "sets" as array columns, like `text[]`, not comma- or space-delimited text. See [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788) for some of the reasons.

You need to watch out for a few things, like the fact that casts between arrays are stricter than casts between their base types. E.g.:

```
regress=> SELECT 'a' = 'a'::varchar, 'b' = 'b'::varchar;
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 t        | t
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT ARRAY['a','b'] = ARRAY['a','b']::varchar[];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] = character varying[]
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY['a','b'] = ARRAY['a','b']::varchar[];
                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
regress=> SELECT ARRAY['a','b']::varchar[] = ARRAY['a','b']::varchar[];
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Such columns are GiST-indexable for operations like array-contains or array-overlaps; see the PostgreSQL documentation on array indexing.

### As normalized rows

The other option is to just store normalized rows with a suitable key. I'd still use `array_agg` for sorting and comparing them, as SQL set operations can be clunky to use for this (especially given the lack of an XOR / double-sided set difference operation).

This is generally known as EAV (entity-attribute-value). I'm not a fan myself, but it does have its place occasionally. Except you'd be using it without the `value` component.

You create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE item_attributes (
    item_id integer references items(id),
    attribute_name text,
    primary key(item_id, attribute_name)
);
```

and insert a row for each set entry for each item, instead of having each item have an array-valued column. The unique constraint enforced by the primary key ensures that no item may have duplicates of a given attribute. Attribute ordering is irrelevant/undefined.

Comparisions can be done with SQL set operators like `EXCEPT`, or using `array_agg(attribute_name ORDER BY attribute_name)` to form consistently sorted arrays for comparison.

Indexing is limited to determining whether a given item has/doesn't have a given attribute.

Personally I'd use arrays over this approach.

### hstore

You can also use hstores with empty values to store sets, as hstore de-duplicates keys. 9.4's `jsonb` will also work for this.

```
regress=# create extension hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION
regress=# SELECT hstore('a => 1, b => 1') = hstore('b => 1, a => 1, b => 1');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

It's only really useful for text types, though. e.g.:

```
regress=# SELECT hstore('"1.0" => 1, "2.0" => 1') = hstore('"1.00" => 1, "1.000" => 1, "2.0" => 1');
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

and I think it's ugly. So again, I'd favour arrays.

### For integer arrays only

The `intarray` extension provides useful, fast functions for treating arrays as sets. They're only available for integer arrays but they're really useful.

Comment: Thanks for laying out the possibilities so clearly.  The db is going to be essentially read-only, so the array approach should be fine.  Using hstore is something I had seen others do, so I might try that at some point if I need to do something more complicated on the server side.

Comment: I'd say the contains operator can also get you where you want to be. It's not a set, but it can get your truth on an unordered where clause. `select aids from testarray where aids @> array[1,2, 3, 11, 33, 22];` returns 
`{1,2,3,11,22,33}`